# featurestore functionality in python/databricks

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I have a function in pyspark as below where each new column is a new feature. For example `journey_email_been_sent_flag`, `journey_opened_flag` ,`journey_clicked_flag`, and `journey_transaction_flag` are new features. I want to create a function in which if a user wants to get one of the mentioned feature, I should be able to retrieve the result for the user.The basic idea behind this is that re-usability of features in central repository. Is there a way to achieve this dynamically for each features.

```
journey_level_revenue_email_open_click = spark.read.parquet(journey_level_revenue_path)
analysis_start_date = "2019-05-06"
def df_ptf_overall(df : DataFrame,startdate : StringType):
  ptf_overall1 = df \
        .filter(F.col('journey_start_date') >= f"{startdate}") \
        .select('bpid',
                'journeyinstanceid',
                'journeyid',
                'journey_start_date',
                'measurement_group',
                'country',
                'email_14days',
                'opened_14days',
                'clicked_14days',
                'testfnemail_14days',
                'testfnopened_14days',
                'testfnclicked_14days',
                'revenue_14days',
                'num_trx_14days',
                'num_items_bought_14days'
                )
  return ptf_overall1

#display(df_ptf_overall(journey_level_revenue_email_open_click,analysis_start_date))

def df_ptf_overall2(df : DataFrame,startdate : StringType):
  ptf_overall2 = df_ptf_overall(df,startdate).filter('measurement_group = "test"') \
    .withColumn('journey_email_been_sent_flag', F.when(F.col('email_14days') > 0, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0))) \
    .withColumn('journey_opened_flag', F.when(F.col('opened_14days') > 0, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0))) \
    .withColumn('journey_clicked_flag', F.when(F.col('clicked_14days') > 0, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0))) \
    .withColumn('journey_transaction_flag', F.when(F.col('revenue_14days') > 0, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0)))
  return ptf_overall2

#display(df_ptf_overall2(journey_level_revenue_email_open_click,analysis_start_date))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

feature_columns = ['journey_email_been_sent_flag','journey_opened_flag']
df = df_ptf_overall(journey_level_revenue_email_open_click,analysis_start_date)

def feature_result(df:DataFrame, features : ArrayType):
input_columns = df.columns
selected_columns = input_columns + feature_columns
return df_ptf_overall2(journey_level_revenue_email_open_click,analysis_start_date).select(*selected_columns).show()

feature_result(df,feature_columns)

I could implement something like this to achieve it

Answer (score 1):

MLflow will be coming out with a formal Feature Store capability soon, so be on the lookout for that. In the mean time why not just add an argument (array or list of strings) with the desired features and then just select those  after creating `ptf_overall2`? You can do something like `DF.select(df_ptf_overall(df,startdate).columns + output_cols)`